# Laravel route is driving me crazy

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Not too long ago it was working absolutely fine and perfect and then I had to go and add pagination and I messed something up, and now I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what I have broken.

So get this:

I have two routes, `dashboard/applications` and `dashboard/applications/filter`

On applications page, you enter your search/filter values then it submits it as GET to the filter page so you can filter through applications

But now it keeps redirecting me back to the applications page without even touching the controller function.

I am losing my mind.

**routes**

```
// Applications
Route::get('dashboard/applications', array(
    'as' => 'dashboard.applications',
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@applications'
));
Route::get('dashboard/applications/filter', array(
   'as' => 'dashboard.applications.filter',
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@applicationsFilter'
));
Route::get('dashboard/applications/{id}', array(
    'as' => 'dashboard.applications.view',
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@applicationsView'
));
```

**DashboardController**

```
    /**
     * Manage user applications
     */
    public function applications()
    {
        $perPage = 10;

        return View::make('dashboard.applications', array(
            'applications' => Application::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($perPage)
        ));
    }


    /**
     * Filter applications
     * By date range, customer, company, email and payment status
     */
    public function applicationsFilter()
    {
        return 'test!';

        // filter code here
    }
```

**view**

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'dashboard.applications.filter', 'method' => 'get')) }}
    // form inputs, textares etc
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Now surely, it should return `test!` when I at least visit the filter page, but no. It simply redirects me back to the applications page. I'm sorry if this is really stupid and I have overlooked something simple but I've gone over this about 30 times now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that `'dashboard/applications/filter'` is being overriden by `'dashboard/applications/{id}'`? After all the first matches the second.

Try changing it to this, and see if it works:

```
// Applications
Route::get('dashboard/applications', array(
    'as' => 'dashboard.applications',
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@applications'
));
Route::get('dashboard/applications/filter', array(
   'as' => 'dashboard.applications.filter',
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@applicationsFilter'
));
Route::get('dashboard/application/{id}', array(
    'as' => 'dashboard.applications.view',
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@applicationsView'
));
```

Comment: Oh my god. How did I not see that. I love you right now!